# What can ONLY be done with CSS, but NOT be done with normal DOM style attributes?

Tags: html, css

I want to know what things can be done "ONLY" with CSS , that are not available using dynamically updated style "attributes" using Javascript. So far I know:

- Media queries
- Pseudo tags

Any more?

**Update:**

This question was closed but I asked it as I am trying to decide on the technology to use for a project, but one of the options cannot use CSS style sheets, and can only manipulate the style attribute using javascript.

Comment: Note that you can modify stylesheets with Javascript, not just inline styles.

Comment: Voting to close as this is essentially a poll question.

Comment: Are you asking about HTML/CSS, or JavaScript/DOM/CSS? You seem to be getting them mixed up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inline style attributes can only contain property declarations (e.g. `width: 10px` or `color: red`). They can't contain any other CSS constructs: not selectors, at-rules (e.g. `@import`, `@media`, `@font-face`), etc. Just property declarations.

However, they play a big role in the cascade: any styles for an element with that attribute take highest precedence (after considering `!important` of course).

There's actually [an entire module devoted to style attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr), by the way, but it's not essential reading for authors.

So, anything that isn't a CSS declaration, is only possible in a stylesheet, not a style attribute. Not sure if that's what you're asking...

Note that media queries and `@media` rules are not the same thing; media queries can exist in areas outside of stylesheets too, like HTML's `media` attribute, where they're next most commonly found.

Comment: Thanks, I meant style attributes, not tags. I updated the question to reflect this :)

Comment: I didn't know that media queries could be used outside of stylesheets. Interesting, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I believe pseudo classes (`:hover` etc..) and pseudo elements (`:after`, `:before`) cannot be added/manipulated via JS (via the style property i mean) because they are not part of the DOM.